# Why won't my break work in my java loop

Tags: java

```
    String prompt;
    boolean promptB;

    runLoop:

    do{
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number, a space and F to convert from degF to degC and C to convert to degC to degF");

        if(input.hasNextDouble()){
            double deg = input.nextDouble();
            String letter = input.next().toUpperCase();
            char dg = letter.charAt(0);

            tempLoop:

            if( dg == 'C' || dg == 'c'){

                double cTemp= (double)(deg-32)*(5.0/9.0);
                System.out.printf("%f degC converted to degF is %.2f%n ", deg, cTemp );
            }
            else if(dg == 'F' || dg == 'f'){
                double fTemp = (double) (deg*9/5) + 32;
                System.out.printf("%f degF converted to degC is %.2f%n ", deg, fTemp );
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That character does not correspond to a valid unit of measure ");
                break tempLoop;
            }
            do{
                System.out.println("Would you like to continue?(yes/no)");
                prompt = input.next().toLowerCase();

                if(prompt.equals("yes")){
                    promptB = false;

                } else if (prompt.equals("no")){
                    promptB = false;
                    break;

                }else{
                    promptB = true;
                    System.out.println("Would you like to continue? yes or no");
                    prompt = input.next();
                }

            }while(promptB);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("must enter in a valid number for degrees");
            break runLoop;
        }
    }while(prompt.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

}
```

}

Here is the code I currently  have. I cannot figure out how to re execute the runLoop: if the input.hasNextDouble() is not true or the user has input letters instead of a double. any info ideas are greatly welcomed

Comment: I would post this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and get some advice on refactoring it. Once its refactored, solving your issue will be trivial.

Comment: well for one, you have the degF and degC mixed up. typing in '32 c' returns '32.000000 degC converted to degF is 0.00'. just a heads up

Comment: thank you for the advice i refactored it and my code is 5 time more simple

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, just change `break runLoop` to `continue runLoop` and it will work just fine. You also need to initialize that `prompt` variable like `String prompt = "yes";`

But you should REALLY refactor this code as it looks error prone like hell.

Comment: Good to hear that, I'm sure Your Java skills will get better and better every day :)

Answer (score 0):

A way to simplify this code would be to place the code in a seperate method and call that method in the main method. for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    runLoop();
}
```

when someone does not enter a double:

```
System.out.println("That character does not correspond to a valid unit of measure ");
runLoop(); //this will restart the method

System.out.println("Would you like to continue?(yes/no)");
prompt = input.next().toLowerCase();
if (prompt.equals("yes")) {
      runLoop();

} else if (prompt.equals("no")) {
       System.exit(1);
```